# error when setting a value for a property between forms

Tags: c#, forms

I'm getting the error:

> cannot implicitly convert type decimal to string

when I'm setting the value for a property and I'm not sure how to remedy this.
There are two forms.  I'm passing information from one form to the other to display it. The error is in Form `Price`

Form (Calculator):

```
  public partial class Calculator : Form
  {       
    decimal dorm = 0;
    decimal meal = 0;            

    public Calculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }     

    public decimal _price
    {
        get { return _price; }
    }

    private void getPriceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal price = 0;

        getInput();

        price = dorm + meal;
        Price myPrice = new Price();
        myPrice._priceLabel = _price;
        myPrice.ShowDialog();            
    }

    private void getInput()
    {
        if(allenRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            dorm = 1500;
        }

        if(pikeRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            dorm = 1600;
        }

        if(farthingRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            dorm = 1800;
        }

        if(universityRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            dorm = 2500;
        }

        if(sevenRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            meal = 600;
        }

        if(fourteenRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            meal = 1200;
        }

        if(unlimitedRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            meal = 1700;
        }
    }
```

Form (Price):

```
public partial class Price : Form
{                   
    public Price()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public decimal _priceLabel
    {
        set { priceLabel.Text = value; }  // error
    }
    priceLabel.Text = price.ToString("c"); //this is messed up too
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you left out some code? `public decimal _price { get { return _price; }  }` looks like it would need a backing field, but the property itself is the backing field. Either declare `public decimal Price { get; set;  }` or `private decimal _price; public decimal Price { get { return _price; }  }`

Comment: Also, your braces in class `Price` don't match up and `priceLabel.Text = price.ToString("c");` looks like it should belong inside a method. If so, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: oh wow...you guys are awesome.  Still having a little bit of an issue but this helped a lot.  Thanks for pointing out the missing backing field

Comment: this is what i did to get it to display to the label.  thanks so much epublic decimal _priceLabel
        {
            set { priceLabel.Text = (value.ToString("c")); }  // error
        }

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, but I would encourage you nonetheless to read up on properties and their usage as there seems to be some confusion about how they work and when to use them. You're assigning a value to `priceLabel.Text` in the setter of a property, but you're not using that property in the rest of your code. Since the `Price` class already has a **field** called `priceLabel`, you don't need to declare an extra *property* `_priceLabel` to set the value of `priceLabel`. Normally you'd only set the value of a backing field in the setter of a property, not that of a different field.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a `String` value to `decimal`. You need to convert it.
Try this:

```
public decimal _priceLabel
    {
        set { priceLabel.Text = decimal.Parse(value); }  // error
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Convert helper class defined here:

[Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Takes a string and converts to the decimal value

For reverse try

Convert.ToString(decimalValue) [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: this sort of worked, but now I get a run time error.  I'll keep working on it.  Thanks